# Data Adaptive technique

Tags: data-analysis

I read in many research paper about the data adaptive analysis techniques. I tried a lot to find the meaning of 'adaptive' in data analysis. What is the main function of the adaptive nature of the analysis technique?

Comment: Without any context, we can't answer this question. Please reformulate this question.

Comment: Perhaps better on Cross Validated or Mathematics... Not really Physics...

Comment: Actually, I am doing data analysis. I used Wavelet transform and now I was trying Hilbert–Huang transform (HHT). In literature read that Hilbert–Huang transform (HHT) is an adaptive technique. I tried to find how it is adaptive or what is the meaning of adaptive in this context. I didn't get any answer.